# IOException When Loading Java Font

Tags: java, fonts, awt, embedded-resource, ioexception

I'm implementing a GUI for a chess program I'm writing for a class. To make it look polished, I want to utilize a Chess Piece Font I obtained from the internet.

The file, chess.ttf, is located at the path Chess/resources/chess.ttf. I utilize the following code per Oracle's instructions (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html):

```
try {
            File file = new File("resources/chess.ttf");

            //Returned font is of pt size 1
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file);

            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file)); 

            //Derive and return a 12 pt version:
            //Need to use float otherwise
            //it would be interpreted as style

            return font.deriveFont(12f);
        } 

    catch (IOException|FontFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("-Font Error-");
        return null;
    }
```

However, this throws an IOException. I ran getAbsolutePath() on the file and received /Users/[me]/eclipse-workspace/Chess/resources/chess.ttf so I'm assuming the file is being loaded correctly. Does anyone know what's going wrong with my code?

edit: Problem resolved? I tried InputStreams as suggested but that didn't work, yet upon reverting my code the computer finally stopped throwing IOExceptions. Isn't code the best?

Comment: Try using `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`. *"I ran getAbsolutePath() on the file and received /Users/[me]/eclipse-workspace/Chess/resources/chess.ttf so I'm assuming the file"* - `File` is an "abstract" representation, it's no guarantee that the `File` actual exists at the specified location - use `exists` for that

Comment: To expand on the earlier part of the comment by @MadProgrammer.. Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better copy the ttf using build script like ant or maven */Users/[me]/eclipse-workspace/Chess/bin/resources*

```
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    System.out.println(loader.getResource(".").getPath()); // for tracing the working folder only
    java.io.InputStream ins = loader.getResourceAsStream("resources/chess.ttf");
    //Returned font is of pt size 1
    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, ins);
```